# convert string to array dynamically in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have working with amcharts (line charts). Set data dynamically with ajax and get the data from php code in JSON format.

Problem comes string is not changed to array dynamically.

if i have add this string static in jquery code

**code:**

```
[{"country":"17 Feb","visits":"4","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"16 Feb","visits":"1","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"15 Feb","visits":"3","color":"#EA5759"}];
```

Thats working fine.

if i have set this code dynamically. line charts shows undefined.

i have use this function

**ajax return code**

[{"country":"17 Feb","visits":"4","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"16 Feb","visits":"1","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"15 Feb","visits":"3","color":"#EA5759"}]

i have just pass this on this function. like

var ajaxString = [{"country":"17 Feb","visits":"4","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"16 Feb","visits":"1","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"15 Feb","visits":"3","color":"#EA5759"}];

### and call this funciton

### lineChart(ajaxString);

function lineChart(data) {
        var chart;

```
    var chartData=data;
    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "country";
    chart.startDuration = 1;
    // AXES
    // category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 45; // this line makes category values to be rotated
    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
    // value
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.dashLength = 5;
    //                                    valueAxis.title = "Visitors from country";
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
    // GRAPH
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.valueField = "visits";
    graph.colorField = "color";
    graph.balloonText = "<b>[[category]]: [[value]] Users</b>";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0.2;
    graph.fillAlphas = 0.9;
    chart.addGraph(graph);
    // CURSOR
    var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
    chartCursor.cursorAlpha = 0;
    chartCursor.zoomable = false;
    chartCursor.categoryBalloonEnabled = false;
    chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);
    chart.creditsPosition = "top-right";
    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
}[![undefined message][1]][1]
```

But thats not working.
Thank You in advance

Comment: how are you dynamically setting the string?

Comment: will get the data from ajax in time of load.

Thats i got from ajax return from php code

Comment: can you show us the code where you set the string statically?

Comment: Static String
        var chartData =[{"country":"17 Feb","visits":"4","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"16 Feb","visits":"1","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"15 Feb","visits":"3","color":"#EA5759"}];

i am using this string dynamically. 

Thats string gots from ajax

[{"country":"17 Feb","visits":"4","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"16 Feb","visits":"1","color":"#EA5759"},{"country":"15 Feb","visits":"3","color":"#EA5759"}]

        var chartData=dataelement;

Comment: There not add my full code here 1200words added in one time

Comment: you should update this in the question, not in the comments section

Comment: Shafeen i have updated my question check please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajaxString that you are passing to your function is simply an string and not a json object , so what your function lineChart might be expecting is json object so try to convert your ajaxString into valid json object before sending it to your function using

```
JSON.parse(ajaxString);
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are attempting to set a JSON **string** to `chartdata` instead of a javascript **object** array.

In this case, you should try to parse your string gotten through the ajax call like so : `JSON.parse(dataelement)` before setting it to `chartdata`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the code dynamically in PHP and covert the array in json via json_encode.
encoded json can be used later in the jquery.